# Help buying good pen for connect-the-dot art

Tags: material-selection, drawing, pens

I got a connect-the-dot book as a gift. I tried multiple pens on it, but all are unsatisfactory. They all have issues like ink running dry often (including in the middle of drawing a line), uneven/inconsistent line thickness (even happens in the same continuous line), and blotchiness (blobs of ink randomly and suddenly spill from pen, which ruins the piece). I would really appreciate a suggestion for a good pen that limits these problems. Thank you very much!

Comment: Product recommendation is off-topic here because availability varies in place and time. That said, recommendations of a type of product are ok, so I'll try to suggest some. What types have you tried? And what's the paper like?

Comment: @ChrisH I've tried generic cheapo pens made by Bic, Papermate and Aspect. Tried some better quality pens, which don't have manufacturer names (the fancy looking pens you get from working at a company). Tried "Sharpie ultra fine point" marker. And I've tried "Pilot Hi-tecpoint V5 extra fine". It's the best, but still has all the problems I mentioned. The paper looks and feels like regular printer paper, feels a small tad thicker, has similar whiteness and gloss.

Answer (score 1):

A liquid ink rollerball would work well if your speed is reasonably constant (pause too long and it will soak in, less so for better quality) that's my preference if I'm doing a lot on paper.

The better quality rollerballs and ballpoint pens (Biros) are a possibility, but the cheap office supply ones often seem to give up partway through a line, as do the more decorative sort.

Various fineliners would work well, especially those sold for engineering drawing. Again, pausing with the pen on the paper isn't a good idea.

If you like to hold the pen on the paper for long periods, a mechanical pencil might be the way to go. That means you're restricted to black (or a very limited range of colours) but a range of thicknesses could be good.

Comment: For the first, I'd try my UniBalls ("ultra" I think), though they may be a little wet. Rotring, Edding, and Staedler make good drawing pens. I mention them so you can get an idea of a price point that should work, even if you can't buy them easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed response! I will check out your suggestions. Will come back with my findings after trying some (if stackexchange lets me, this is my first post so idk)